# How do companies such as Gmail detect email spoofing

Tags: email, spoofing

If you send a spoof email to a Gmail account, Gmail detects this somehow, and puts this email in your "spam" folder.

How does this work?

Comment: Using Google's secret spam detection filters, which are presumably based on known email validation techniques.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

Google checks [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) to find out what servers (and signatures) are required for mail sent from a domain name.